Why doesn't Playwright reporter wait for async functions to complete?
I am using custom playwright reporter (but I think this issue is not only tied to reporter) and there in async OnTestEnd(test, result) I am trying to run exec command. With debugger turned on I see that as soon as program reaches this exec function it skips it and it ends.
const { exec } = require('child_process');

class CustomPDFReporter {
  onTestEnd(test, result) {
    const cmd = `C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe --quiet --print-media-type ...`;

    exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`Error executing command: ${error.message}`);
        return;
      }

      if (stderr) {
        console.error(`Error output: ${stderr}`);
        return;
      }

      console.log("Generation successful!");
      console.log(`Command Output: ${stdout}`);
    });
  }
}

module.exports = CustomPDFReporter;

Above is one of many attempts to correctly run this function. But it skips all the time.

judging from here https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters#custom-reporters it seems that onTestEnd isn't supposed to be async.. but yet you can deal with promises as long as its operations await for their promises to be resolved before returning.. can you verify yourself if that's the culprit?

Hello, I tried it and it still skips the function unfortunately. Behavior is the same as before.

for the sake of records.. how did you implement the onTestEnd function? because of course you shouldn't return a Promise anymore if the function isn't async. Can you just update the question to reflect the latest information learnt? The https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-reporter shows that onTestEnd is not async and so far the answer to the question you asked is: Playwright doesn't wait for onTestEnd to finish as long as it's async. The function call ends as soon as the Promise is returned

ok so probably issue lies somewhere else and not in async, but behavior stays the same.

that's because exec is async and yet the onTestEnd function call will return before its operation completed. Try using execSync instead

Omg Thanks! I spent 2 days on that presuming that onTestEnd is async, tried everything. You saved me

As mentioned in the comments, use execSync instead of the async callback version exec:
const {execSync} = require("child_process");

class CustomPDFReporter {
  onTestEnd(test, result) {
    const cmd = `C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe --quiet --print-media-type ...`;
    
    try {
      const {stdout, stderr} = execSync(cmd);

      if (stderr) {
        console.error(`Error output: ${stderr}`);
        return;
      }

      console.log("Generation successful!");
      console.log(`Command Output: ${stdout}`);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error executing command: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = CustomPDFReporter;

If you happened to be in an async function, you can promisify exec to avoid its callback running in a separate promise chain (shown in vanilla Node):
const {promisify} = require("util");
const exec = promisify(require("child_process").exec);

(async () => {
  try {
    const {stderr, stdout} = await exec("ls"); // or "dir" on windows

    if (stderr) {
      console.error(`Error output: ${stderr}`);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Generation successful!");
      console.log(`Command Output: ${stdout}`);
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error executing command: ${err.message}`);
  }
})();

